# Prevent templated class from using itself as instance

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I have a class template

```cpp
template<class T>
class Foo{};
```

Is it possible to prevent T from being an instantiation of Foo. That is, this should not compile:

```cpp
struct Bar{};

Foo<Foo<Bar>> x;
```

Comment: I remember I see exactly this question some day. I am curious how do you comes up with this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct ValidFooArg;

template <typename T>
requires ValidFooArg<T>::value
class Foo
{

};

template <typename T>
struct ValidFooArg : std::true_type {};
template <typename T>
struct ValidFooArg<Foo<T>> : std::false_type {};

int main()
{
    Foo<int> x; // ok
    Foo<Foo<int>> y; // error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might still provide partial specialization to have error in that case:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool always_false = false;

template<class T>
class Foo<Foo<T>>
{
    static_assert(always_false<T>);
};
```

Comment: Or `requires always_false<T>` for SFINAE-friendliness.